# Google App Script - App Script is deleting the \n when Script is Ran

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am writing a function to Split an Address by a \n delimiter

```
  spreadsheet.getRange('AX1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('=ARRAYFORMULA(if(ROW(L1:L)=1,"Owner2 Street Split",(split(W1:W,"/\n/",FALSE))))');
```

Everytime I ran the script, this is the formula that is applied to the row.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(ROW(L1:L)=1,"Business Street Split",(split(L1:L,"
",FALSE))))
```

Running the script Automatically removed the \n as a delimiter. Is there any way to bypass this?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(ROW(L1:L)=1,"Business Street Split",(split(L1:L,"\n",FALSE))))
```

Answer (score 0):

To produce a backslash In JavaScript, you need double escape it. `\n` will produce a newline, so your current code will not output `\n` but a literal newline character. To produce `\n`, use `\\n`.

In a Google Sheets formula, `\n` does not represent a newline character. Use `char(10)` instead.